# How to save console output to a file?

Tags: c#, file, output

I was wondering if somebody could help me, Im trying to save my console output to a file but it only takes one output and i want it to take and append the output everytime it shows in the console (more or less every second),i tried some different methods but nothing seems to work and im not even sure if this is possible.

1) This was my first try: it only takes one console output, but as i understood it should redirect it.

```
                FileStream ostrm;
                StreamWriter writer;
                TextWriter oldOut = Console.Out;
                try
                {
                    ostrm = new FileStream("C:/Users/Joanne/Desktop/WriteLines3.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                    writer = new StreamWriter(ostrm);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cannot open Redirect.txt for writing");
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    return;
                }
                while(onvifPTZ != null) { 
                Console.SetOut(writer);
                Console.WriteLine("\t Act Value [" + curPan.ToString() +
                                                       "," + curTilt.ToString() +
                                                       "," + curZoom.ToString() + "]");
                Console.WriteLine("\t Ref Value [" + newPTZRef.pan.ToString() +
                                                       "," + newPTZRef.tilt.ToString() +
                                                       "," + newPTZRef.zoom.ToString() + "]");
                Console.WriteLine("\t Dif Value [" + dPan.ToString() +
                                                   "," + dTilt.ToString() +
                                                   "," + dZoom.ToString() + "]");
                Console.SetOut(oldOut);
                writer.Close();
                ostrm.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

2)And those two without redirecting the console

```
/*while (onvifPTZ != null)
                {


                    string[] lines = {"\t Act Value [" + curPan.ToString() +
                                                       "," + curTilt.ToString() +
                                                       "," + curZoom.ToString() + "]","\t Ref Value [" + newPTZRef.pan.ToString() +
                                                       "," + newPTZRef.tilt.ToString() +
                                                       "," + newPTZRef.zoom.ToString() + "]", "\t Dif Value [" + dPan.ToString() +
                                                   "," + dTilt.ToString() +
                                                   "," + dZoom.ToString() + "]" + Environment.NewLine };

                        string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

                    using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(mydocpath, "WriteLines1.txt")))
                    {
                        foreach (string line in lines)
                            outputFile.WriteLine(line);
                        outputFile.Flush();
                    }
```

3)

```
/* string path = @"c://Users//Joanne//Desktop//WriteLines.txt";

                   if (!File.Exists(path))
                   {
                       // Create a file to write to.
                      using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                       {
                           while(onvifPTZ!=null){ 
                           sw.WriteLine("\t Act Value [" + curPan.ToString() +
                                                          "," + curTilt.ToString() +
                                                          "," + curZoom.ToString() + "]");
                           sw.WriteLine("\t Ref Value [" + newPTZRef.pan.ToString() +
                                                          "," + newPTZRef.tilt.ToString() +
                                                          "," + newPTZRef.zoom.ToString() + "]");
                           sw.WriteLine("\t Dif Value [" + dPan.ToString() +
                                                      "," + dTilt.ToString() +
                                                      "," + dZoom.ToString() + "]");
                               sw.Flush();
                               //sw.Close();
                           }
                       }
                   }


                  /*using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path)) {
                           while (onvifPTZ != null)
                           {


                               sw.WriteLine("\t Act Value [" + curPan.ToString() +
                                                              "," + curTilt.ToString() +
                                                              "," + curZoom.ToString() + "]");
                               sw.WriteLine("\t Ref Value [" + newPTZRef.pan.ToString() +
                                                              "," + newPTZRef.tilt.ToString() +
                                                              "," + newPTZRef.zoom.ToString() + "]");
                               sw.WriteLine("\t Dif Value [" + dPan.ToString() +
                                                          "," + dTilt.ToString() +
                                                          "," + dZoom.ToString() + "]");
                           sw.Flush();
                           //sw.Close();
                           }


                       }
                   using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
                   {
                       string s = "";
                       while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                       {
                           Console.WriteLine(s);
                       }
                   }




                  // Open the file to read from.
                  /* using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
                   {
                       string s;
                       while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                       {
                           Console.WriteLine(s);
                       }
                   }*/
```

Nothing seems to work properly...
My console looks like that, for every move the camera does it appends a value:

```
[1003]
myTimedFunction got called at 1003
     Act Value [2.777576E-05,0,0]
     Ref Value [0.06279052,0.0125581,0.06279052]
     Dif Value [0.06276274,0.0125581,0.06279052]
[2006]
myTimedFunction got called at 2006
     Act Value [2.777576E-05,0,0.020052]
     Ref Value [0.1253332,0.02506665,0.1253332]
     Dif Value [0.1253055,0.02506665,0.1052812]
[3006]
myTimedFunction got called at 3006
     Act Value [0.06586289,0.02461553,0.06845684]
     Ref Value [0.1873813,0.03747626,0.1873813]
     Dif Value [0.1215184,0.01286074,0.1189245]
[4007]
myTimedFunction got called at 4007
     Act Value [0.09025252,0.02461553,0.1652665]
     Ref Value [0.2486899,0.04973798,0.2486899]
     Dif Value [0.1584374,0.02512245,0.08342336]
[5008]
myTimedFunction got called at 5008
     Act Value [0.1146421,0.02461553,0.2651765]
     Ref Value [0.309017,0.0618034,0.309017]
     Dif Value [0.1943749,0.03718787,0.0438405]
[6008]
myTimedFunction got called at 6008
     Act Value [0.1300313,0.02461553,0.3089309]
     Ref Value [0.3681245,0.07362491,0.3681245]
     Dif Value [0.2380932,0.04900938,0.05919364]
[7009]
myTimedFunction got called at 7009
     Act Value [0.1453651,0.02461553,0.3681368]
     Ref Value [0.4257793,0.08515586,0.4257793]
     Dif Value [0.2804142,0.06054033,0.05764246]
[8009]
myTimedFunction got called at 8009
     Act Value [0.1606989,0.02461553,0.4256926]
     Ref Value [0.4817537,0.09635074,0.4817537]
     Dif Value [0.3210548,0.07173521,0.05606112]
[9010]
myTimedFunction got called at 9010
     Act Value [0.1850885,0.02461553,0.4815482]
     Ref Value [0.5358268,0.1071654,0.5358268]
     Dif Value [0.3507383,0.08254983,0.05427864]
[10010]
myTimedFunction got called at 10010
     Act Value [0.1935887,0.02461553,0.5225022]
     Ref Value [0.5877852,0.117557,0.5877852]
     Dif Value [0.3941965,0.09294152,0.065283]
[11010]
myTimedFunction got called at 11010
     Act Value [0.2179784,0.02461553,0.5454546]
     Ref Value [0.637424,0.1274848,0.637424]
     Dif Value [0.4194456,0.1028693,0.09196943]
```

But actually my files I created only take the first value and nothing more...

Comment: Have you tried FileMode.Append instead?

Comment: Remove your `StreamWriter` code in your 2nd try and replace it will `File.AppendText(Path.Combine(mydocpath, "WriteLines1.txt"), string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));` - could also call `File.AppendText(Path.Combine(mydocpath, "WriteLines1.txt"), line);` for each individual line

Comment: Are you looking for [FileMode.Append](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=netframework-4.7.2)?Also you can redirect output to file like that `yourApplication.exe >> c:\saveYourOutput.txt`

Comment: How should i write it with FileMode.Append?

Comment: Replace `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` with `FileMode.Append`

Answer (score 0):

The approach with your first attempt is correct but your Console.SetOut was wrong. Check the code piece written below:

```
using (var ostrm = new FileStream("C:/Users/dervis.kayimbasioglu/Desktop/WriteLines3.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(ostrm))
{
    Console.SetOut(writer);
    Console.WriteLine("test to be written in file");
    writer.Close();
    ostrm.Close();
}

Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

Comment: I tried both, changing that and changing to FileMode.Append, but now its telling me that i cannot write to a closed TextWriter  :/ any idea how to fix?

Comment: writer.close() is closing writer. I dont know why It is not working for you,

Answer (score 0):

**Dirty solution**
Store your console output in an array, and when you close your application store it with

```
File.WriteAllLines("path", array);
```

**Recommended solution**
Use one of many logging libraries like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html). I use it by myself in some of my projects and I can really recommend it. It also has a NuGet package that you can download via the menu *"manage nuget packages"* by right clicking your project.

Here a small example how to use the log4net logger

```
var log=LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

log.Info("Hello World");
```

Also you need to create a config file with the name **log4net.config**. Here you have a config example that I used [from this site](https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/), when I started with log4net

```
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
  <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>
<appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="myapp.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
</log4net>
```

And last you need to add this line to your **AssemblyInfo.cs** the following line, that your program loads the config file

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]
```

I hope my awnser was helpfull